# OS-X & IZPack: user friendly ways to run installer on OS-X computers with NO Java installed

Tags: java, macos, installation, izpack

Our users work on Mac OS-X and new versions of OS-X have no Java pre-installed.
Further I do not want to bother them with installing Java.

Is there a user friendly way to install programs with IZPack?
Can I create a zip with the installer.jar and JRE together?

Any samples?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a Mac, I can think of 2 ways to skin this cat.

1. Using the Mac wrapper from launch4j. Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.1.0-beta2/

This will prompt the user to download the JRE if it is not present or embed the JRE to the installer.

1. Downloading a portable version of a JRE for Mac and create your own Application.app folder that can execute the installer

Note that in any case, you must have a JRE to run the installer which will make your installer fatter or will prompt the user for action.